# ¿Cómo obtengo la diferencia de días entre una fecha y otra traídas desde inputs con el formato dd/mm/aa con js puro?

Tags: javascript

```js
let checkIn = document.getElementById('check-in'); //fecha de arrivo
let checkOut = document.getElementById('check-out'); //fecha de salida
// De aquí obtengo los inputs por id
function howManyDays(date1, date2) {
  let totalMs = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  let days = totalMs = Math.round(totalMs / msPerDay);
  console.log(days)
}
```

```html
<label for="check">Check-in</label> </div> <input type="date" name="date-in" id="check-in"> </div>
<div class="check">
  <div class="block"> <i class="bi bi-calendar-check"></i> <label for="check">Check-out</label> </div> <input type="date" name="date-out" id="check-out"> </div>
```

Y en lo segundo es la función para calcular los días. El problema es que no sé cómo traer los valores que se ingresan en los inputs. Si yo tipeo la fecha (con el formato aa/mm/dd) la función anda bien. Pero el problema es el que describo.

Comment: ¿Cómo están en el HTML los inputs _check-in_ y _check-out_? Tené en cuenta también que «_el formato de la fecha mostrada diferirá del valor real: la fecha mostrada se formatea en función de la configuración regional del navegador del usuario, pero el valor analizado_ (parseado) _siempre tiene el formato `aaaa-mm-dd`._» (nota extraída de [la documentación de `<input type="date">` en MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)).

Comment: Así está mi html: `<label for="check">Check-in</label>
                  </div>
                   <input type="date" name="date-in" id="check-in">        
                 </div>
                 <div class="check">
                   <div class="block">
                     <i class="bi bi-calendar-check"></i>
                   <label for="check">Check-out</label>
                   </div>
                   <input type="date" name="date-out" id="check-out">
                 </div>`

Comment: ya intenaste con `.value`?

Comment: si.. en la consola cuando pongo checkIn.value me trae la fecha, y undefined debajo

Comment: creo que el problema radica en el formato de la fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `valueAsDate` para que el input devuelva la fecha como un objeto `Date`:

```
function howManyDays(date1, date2) {
  let totalMs = Math.abs(date2.valueAsDate - date1.valueAsDate);
  let days = totalMs / (60*60*24*1000);
  console.log(days);
}
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias!